# laravel eloquent - Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have problem with my code. I have in db two tables,
 **'automakers' with fields (id_am, name)** and **'car_models' with fields (id_cm, name, id_am)** witch is related to table automakers by id_am field. One automakers can have many models. In my code that's looks like this:
**Automakers**

```php
class Automakers extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'automakers';

    public $primaryKey = 'id_am';

    public function carModels(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\CarModels', 'id_am', 'id_am');
    }
}
```

**CarModels**

```php
class CarModels extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'car_models';

    public $primaryKey = 'id_cm';

    public function carModels()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Automakers', 'id_am', 'id_am');
    }
}
```

Now when I try to retrive in view automakers name I have error

> Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.

**My controller code**

```php
public function create($id)
    {
        $models = CarModels::find($id)->carModels->name;        

        return view('cars.models')->with('models', $models);
    }
```

Do I do something wrong?

Comment: Why do you have a relationship in your `CarModels` class called `carModels` and not `automaker`?

Comment: I'm never sure how to look exactly like it

Comment: Do dd(CarModels::find($id)->carModels) and make sure that the property name exists in the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the relationship name in your CarModel.

```
public function autoMaker()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Automakers', 'id_am');
}
```

In Controller just change the relationship name:

```
public function create($id)
{
    $models = CarModels::find($id)->autoMaker->name;        

    return view('cars.models')->with('models', $models);
}
```

Note: Please Follow the naming convention of Laravel to avoid this kind of situation. Your Model Name should be singular.

Comment: Ok this has changed something. Now i get error "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object." Database is not empty.

Comment: Because the name property is only accessible in a loop, automaker returns a collection of data

Comment: Do you have values in both tables? And do values match? Like id_am in car_models table and Id_am in auto_makers table  are same?

Comment: @OSKaya belongsTo relationship returns only one object. You need not to loop it.

Comment: For now there is only one value in both tables. One record for both.

Comment: Do id_am in car_models is same as id_am of auto_makers?

Comment: unfortunately yes

Comment: then do dd($id); in the create function to check the id value is same as the database

Comment: unfortunately yes. Maybe there is another way to retrive that value?

Comment: This should work. Maybe there are some other issues in your code. Can you check with one foreign key like my updated answer?

Comment: And you can try this too to check model instance. $models = CarModel::find($id); then dd($models); to check if it exists.

Comment: when I do $models = CarModel::find($id); and dd($models); in all that informations there something like #relations: []. It show empy []. Should it be like that?